# C SIGALARM clarification

Tags: c, signals

*"Rewrite 'fgets' to include an alarm so that if after 5 seconds the user doesn't enter any data, 'fgets' will return a pointer to NULL (times out)"*

This one problem of a large homework assignment and we only just starting to look at signals, catching, handling, etc.  With that said the book and lecture slides are lacking on this...

I get the idea of creating a handler to catch this type of exception, and I understand how alarm works, but I don't understand how the interface will work.

Just thinking about "fgets" right now...  If I simply put an alarm in it prior to all the other work being done (just before my return pointer):

```
char *fgets(//...//)
{
    alarm(5);
    char * to_return = NULL;
    //...//
```

If the alarm goes off before the user types in data, can my handler just "return NULL"?  Won't execution resume back within "fgets" after the handler is done?  I guess I'm confused by what a handler can do inside of a function (ie can it force the function to return some value, can it modify variables that are declared within the function, can it force a jump to a different function call, etc.)

Comment: It's unclear what the assignment is. Normally if you want to do this, no "rewrite" of `fgets` is necessary; you can just install the signal handler using `sigaction` without `SA_RESTART` and `fgets` will automatically fail when the underlying `read` gets `EINTR`.

Comment: If you want to do it without that (and without race conditions), `longjmp` is your friend.

Answer (score 1):

First off, a signal handler is a **separate** thread of execution. When the signal is raised, the "normal" execution of your code is interrupted, the signal handler executed, and once the handler returns, execution of your code is resumed at the point it was interrupted.

So, 1) your signal handler cannot effect a return from your `fgets()` (at least not directly), and 2) it cannot return a value. (You might note that the `signal()` function, which installs a signal handler, demands a pointer to *a function taking an integer as parameter and **having a `void` return type***.

What a signal handler *can* do is to set a value. The standard (C99, chapter "Signal handling", 7.14.1.1 (5)) says on this:

> If the signal occurs other than as the result of calling the `abort` or `raise` function, the
>   behavior is undefined if the signal handler refers to any object with static storage duration
>   other than by assigning a value to an object declared as `volatile sig_atomic_t`, or
>   the signal handler calls any function in the standard library other than the `abort`
>   function, the `_Exit` function, or the `signal` function with the first argument equal to
>   the signal number corresponding to the signal that caused the invocation of the handler.

What this means is, you can declare a variable of type `volatile sig_atomic_t` where both your `fgets()` and your signal handler can "see" it, initialize it to a default value, and have the signal handler change that value so your `fgets()` can see that the signal fired.

Of course, if your `fgets()` waits until the user enters something, it would wait even after the signal fired... how to solve that is a matter of how you are doing the input. Either you use a non-blocking check for input like `getch()` (which isn't ISO/ANSI C), or you rely on the behaviour of `read()` that R. mentioned (which is relying on a POSIX layer underneath `fgets()`), or something else. I cannot think on a strictly ISO/ANSI C way to do this, so it depends on what you already learned / did in your course.

Oh, and if you feel brave, tell your instructor that it is a *really* bad idea (to avoid calling him "stupid") to redefine standard functions to a different behaviour. If you want a `fgets()` that isn't really `fgets()`, give it a different name, e.g. `fgets_timed()`.

Comment: `longjmp` out of a signal is not "use only in emergency as `goto` and proprocessor magic", it is, unlike them, outright undefined behavior (cf. async-signal safe functions).

Comment: Indeed - as it says clearly in the quoted part of the standard. I missed that, thanks.

Comment: `fgetc` (or `getchar`) is the C version of `getch`. But if the libc `fgets` can be called then it should abort on a caught signal, and no further action is needed.

Comment: @PerJohansson: Why should the libc fgets() abort when a signal is caught? It's a signal, not an exception. Or have I missed something?

Comment: @DevSolar All read/write libc calls abort when a signal is caught, if they're accessing something else than a file. They don't if the signal is ignored or blocked however (blocking signals is a POSIX extension). Just noticed that SIGALRM is also an extension, btw.